# Retain Object state across viewmodels MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, class, object, mvvm

This might sound very basic but, excuse me here and let me know possible solutions. I use MVVM pattern in my application and I am pretty newbie to it.

I have a Parent View(say 'StudentView') with its viewmodel(StudentViewmodel)

StudentView holds two controls - Tablinks and a 'Save button'

- Tablinks will have link to each View (like Academic, Personal, etc). This will be like treeview with two panes. I load the page in right pane with the heading in left pane. Each view has its own Viewmodel with corresponding properties
- User is allowed to edit the values in each view which are bound to VM's properties.
- User is allowed to navigate across each tab and make the changes which will update the properties in corresponding VM
- Now, when user hits Save button in 'StudentViewModel', I need to call 'Save' method in each VM(like Academic, Personal) and get its reference for those object which is holding the updated properties and push to my Controller.

The problem is very simple here. When I invoke the Save method of AcademicViewModel, it is going to create a new instance and I can't get hold of the modified object which was initiated through Tablinks.

Is there any work around here other than making these properties Static?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Because, I need to invoke this Save method from a different viewmodel. It is not a static method. Its an instance method and so, I would need a object to invoke it.

Comment: This `"Tablinks will have link to each View"` is wrong. In MVVM you use [data templates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html). In `StudentViewModel` should be some observable collection of base for child viewmodels class. Then your child viewmodels call `StudentViewModel` methods to do stuff: add items, edit, delete, etc. Obviously you pass `StudentViewModel` instance ot child views (or make it available somehow, `static` property could do too). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14811820/1997232) if you want to use dialogs.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why the Save method is going to create a new instance of your ViewModel instead of using the existing instance.  That should not be the case.  It would help if you included some relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DI Containers solved my problem here.